# Ajax call to ASP.NEt Web Api method. Parser error when it is done from HTTPS page

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "api/basket",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        error: function (request, status, error) {
             alert(request.responseText);
        },
         success: function (data) {
                  Process(data);
        }
    });
```

I use ASP.NEN Web forms, .Net Framework 4.0, there is an ajax call above which I make . And when it is done from normal HTTP page it gives me data, But if I make this call being on HTTPS page it returns parserror "Unexpected token <"

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax request isn't returning JSON, it is returning HTML or XML. Thus, when jQuery attempts to parse the response, the first character is sees is `<` and it throws the parse error.

Use a debugging tool such as fiddler to see exactly what your request returns.

Comment: Aparently yes, but how to make it return a json? I already set  dataType: "json"

Comment: Setting `dataType: 'JSON'` simply tells jQuery that you are "expecting" a JSON response and to parse it as such; it doesn't actually force the server to return JSON. You need to configure your API on the server to actually return JSON.

Comment: The thing is , that web api method isn't even hit (in debug) , when it is called from https page

Comment: request.responseText <html><head><title></title><!-- <script language="javascript">window.location.replace("http://localhost/../WebSite_R6/Website/api/basket");</script> --></head><body></body></html>

Comment: It is returning a redirect; I don't know why it would. There is maybe some configuration option which is redirecting SSL traffic to just HTTP. Ajax requests will not follow redirects.

Comment: in web.config nothing, where to check?